# TextFormField clearing after click off

Tags: flutter, dart

When a `TextFormField` is filled in, the input vanishes when clicking off. It is within a `StatefulWidget`.

I'm guessing this has something to do with state?.. I am using identical logic to another page in the application, yet I can't get this page to work.

```
class EditContact extends StatefulWidget {
EditContact({Key key, @required this.contact}) : super(key: key);
 final Contact contact;
@override
_EditContactState createState() => _EditContactState();}


class _EditContactState extends State<EditContact> {
@override

Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    final oneController = TextEditingController();
    final twoController = TextEditingController();
    final threeController = TextEditingController();
    final fourController = TextEditingController();
    final fiveController = TextEditingController();
    final sixController = TextEditingController();
    final sevenController = TextEditingController();

    ...

    TextFormField(
      controller: oneController,
      decoration: textInputDecoration.copyWith(hintText: 'Name'),
    ),
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you should not initialize controllers inside of the build method!

The problem is that with the code above you are re-creating a new controller (with no text) every time the page is built again and this is clearing the text field. To fix that, initialize your controllers out of the build method.

```dart
class EditContact extends StatefulWidget {
EditContact({Key key, @required this.contact}) : super(key: key);
 final Contact contact;
@override
_EditContactState createState() => _EditContactState();}


class _EditContactState extends State<EditContact> {


  final oneController = TextEditingController();
  final twoController = TextEditingController();
  final threeController = TextEditingController();
  final fourController = TextEditingController();
  final fiveController = TextEditingController();
  final sixController = TextEditingController();
  final sevenController = TextEditingController();

  @override
  void dispose() {
    // dispose your controllers here
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    // ..... your code
  }
}
```

Note that you can initialize your controllers inside of the initState as well!